# Can we make Two Containers with Identically named members in VB.Net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, containers

I am trying to make array of containers of either of these Panel, GroupBox, Table etc. (Any will work) 
Within each container there shall be
label: lblMoment
Text Box: txtMoment

and some unique to container like
lblAstCompression
txtCompression etc

I want containers like:

```
containers(0).txtMoment=56.0
container(1).txtMoment=78.0

container(1).txtCompression = 34345.0
```

In summary, I want container which OWNS its child control so that I can access children using parent's name/index etc.
Array shall be Array of Containers (if possible)

I hope there is a solution to this :)

Comment: Use `UserControl`s

Comment: Please elaborate :)